# php7 shimmying type keywords to facilitate transition

Tags: php, types

I want to improve my php5 codebase and make it ready for php7.  alas, for code that I want to run on a php5 interpreter, I would like to do the C preprocessor equivalent of

```
 #define int
 #define float
 #define string
 #define bool
```

and perhaps

```
 #define array
```

so that

```
 function(int $x) {...}
```

is seen by php5 to be the same as

```
 function($x) {...}
```

it would also clarify the meaning of my code to me, even if it does not trigger anything in the interpreter itself.

is this possible?

Comment: Besides the fact that there's no straightforward way to do this, did you realise that you could already typehint `array` anyway

Comment: so basically you want something that compile php7-like syntax into plain php5? you should just be running php7 then...